# How do I save a users check mark selection in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am currently trying to save a users check mark selection in iOS. I have a custom made empty check box and a box with the check mark. I have gotten to change when I click it, but I am unsure how to save the checkmark to user defaults after the app is closed. I know how to do this for text and slider buttons but I just can't figure it out for these images. I am programming in Swift and your help is very much appreciated. I already have some of the code setup but I could be wrong on it all.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewChallengeTrackerTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    //checkboxes
    @IBOutlet weak var checkBoxButton1: UIButton!

    var saveCheckBoxes = UserDefaults.standard

    //saving keys
    let checkBoxSave01 = "checkBoxSave01"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //check box #1 images
        checkBoxButton1.setImage(UIImage(named:"greyUnchecked"), for: .normal)
        checkBoxButton1.setImage(UIImage(named:"greyChecked"), for: .selected)

         //loading the saved check box
        if saveCheckBoxes.object(forKey: checkBoxSave01) != nil{

        }
    }

    //check box changed/check box had heptic/saving user selection
    let impact = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: UIImpactFeedbackStyle.medium)

    @IBAction func checkBoxTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        saveCheckBoxes.set(sender.currentImage, forKey: checkBoxSave01)

        impact.impactOccurred()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.0, y: 0.0)

        }) { (success) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
                sender.transform = .identity
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the value as a boolean, not as the image. Then when you load this view controller, get that boolean value from defaults. If it is true, check the checkbox. If it is false, do not check the checkbox.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "checkBoxSave01")
```

When trying to setup the checkboxes later, you can do something like this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "checkBoxSave01") == true {
    // Configure the checkbox as checked
} else {
    // Configure the checkbox as unchecked
}
```

`bool(forKey:)` will return true if the value set at that key is true. It will return false if the value was set to false or if there is no value at that key.

Comment: So in the viewdidload, I would do an “if” statement, but I’m confused on how to set that up to grab the users selection. Like if you look at my statement in the viewdidload, it is just wrong.

Comment: Also I am very new to swift and that’s why I’m asking for more detailed help. I’m trying to get better at the code and I’ve spent a few hours trying to figure this out. That’s why I’m asking.

Comment: The call to `synchronize` should not be used. In fact, it is marked as obsolete in the documentation.

Comment: @rmaddy Huh, I didn't realize. Apple should probably deprecate the method. I'll remove it from my answer. I haven't used UserDefaults in a while apparently :)

Comment: @IanSp Added info on retrieving the value.

Comment: I’m assuming I’d do this or is there a better way of doing it and I’m really sorry if this is getting annoying.`if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:”checkBoxSave01”) == true { checkBoxButton1.setImage(UIImage(named: “greyUnchecked”), for: .normal) else{ checkBoxButton1.setImage(UIImage(named: “greyChecked”), for: .selected) }`

Comment: @IanSp There are many ways to accomplish any programming task. That will work fine. There are definitely ways it could be improved: use constants instead of the raw string names, use a ternary expression to set a image name var and then pass that to the setImage to reduce code duplication, etc, but what you have will work for now. A lot of that comes with experience.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for your help. I am a beginner, so it’s awesome to have people like you who would take time to help someone like me with this. I am constantly trying to improve and learn more about this language and you’ve helped a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. And you can easily modify it to suit your needs.

```
enum UserDefaultsKeys : String {
    case someBox
    case anotherBox
}

extension UserDefaults{

    func setSomeBox(value : Bool){
        set(value, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.someBox.rawValue)
    }

    func getSomeBox() -> Bool {
        return bool(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.someBox.rawValue)
    }

    func setAnotherBox(value : Bool){
        set(value, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.anotherBox.rawValue)
    }

    func GetAnotherBox() -> Bool {
        return bool(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.anotherBox.rawValue)
    }
}
```